# How do i automatically import a new csv file from my local pc to google sheets every minute?

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-colaboratory

i have a csv file in my computer that gets updated every minute. i currently know how to import this csv file to google sheets manually. is there an automatic way to import the csv file each minute and overwrite the data that is in the current sheet? i tried using IMPORTDATA() but it needs a url instead of retrieving from local drive

Comment: Write a cron job and let us know how it goes. Or use some scheduled notebook capabilities.

Comment: @HashRocketSyntax do you have some code you could direct me to?

Comment: You need to change your mindset to "here is the exact code that i have tried, here is my error, help me figure out why or what i should do differently" post your code

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I would recommend trying the absolute file address as a parameter passed to `IMPORTDATA()`. Like this:

```
IMPORTDATA("file:///C:/Users/myUserName/myFolder/myData.csv")
```

Another idea would be to [sync your Google Drive with the local file](http://www.speedofcreativity.org/2016/12/12/selectively-auto-sync-local-files-to-google-drive/). This way, you can provide a URL as input.

Comment: IMPORTDATA() function does not work like that. The importdata function can access only access publicly-available web pages via their URL. So, if you created a webersver on the machine with the CSV and made it live on the internet, then the function could reach it